# how can I embed google contacts or calendar in to my php webpage

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-contacts-api

I want either the ability to search contacts from the website or display some

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you studied the Google APIs, however, you can use classes that make the integration for you.

To create an show events in google calendar direct from your page.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5729-PHP-Create-events-in-a-Google-calendar.html

To import and manage google contacts.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5043-PHP-Import-contacts-from-Gmail.html